# Calling javascript function in case of partial rendering using AJAX from server side c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I want to make visible the `<tr>` of a `<table>` which is inside an `asp:update panel`,
but I am not able to make it visible through a call from C# server side.
The following is the code I am calling from server side.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "Test();", true);
```

I have the Test() function in my aspx page.

Comment: what's the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

Place Literal control(keep id as "ltlScript") in update panel and set EnableViewState = false and in code-behind call your js function using following way.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(ltlScript, ltlScript.GetType, "myScript", "Test();",true);
```